# Retrieve all Tasks current iteration for specific user

Tags: rally

I want to retrieve all current tasks for a specific user through the .NET C# API. (WS 2.0)

QueryString: `(((Owner.UserName = "xxx") AND (Iteration.StartDate <= today)) AND (Iteration.EndDate >= today))` (works by trying in https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)

With the below code I get a `404` exception.

```
     Request request = new Request("task");
     request.Fetch = new List<string>()
     {
       "_refObjectName"
     };
     request.Query = new Query("Owner.UserName", Query.Operator.Equals, "xxx");
```

Can you help out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Rest Toolkit has not yet been updated to work with the newly released WSAPI 2.0 yet.  Look for a new version to be released soon.  In the meantime please use version 1.43.

Comment: can you pls take a look at this question and try and give me a solution..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124447/data-for-calculating-vellocity-chart-in-rally.. Would really appreciate it